# How to filter data in collection using asp.net with EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using EF in my project and i fill my Datagridview  with collection see below...

```
 private void FillGrid()
        {
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["testID"]);
            var data = dbData.tbltest2.Where(x => x.ID== ID && x.testIsDeleted == false && x.testStatus == 1).ToList();
            if (data.Count > 0)
            {
                grdViewtestList.DataSource = data;
                grdViewtestList.DataBind();
                Session["JobListData"] = data;
            }
            else
            {
                grdViewtestList.DataSource = null;
                grdViewtestList.DataBind();
            }

        }
```

i wont to use RowFilter with data which is i fill my Data Gridview . 
so can you please tell me how can i use rowfilter with collection in EF.

anyone please help me it's argent.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ see this

Comment: thanks for suggestion but this one i know . actually i have a collection of data and i can't use rowfilter with collection data. Mean i don't datatable and dataset. i have collection of data and  i wont filter my data. actually i am useing searching in my page.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot - `RowFilter` is feature of `DataSet` based data binding. You must pass your filter value in other control - for example some text box and use it in LINQ query.